# Google Cloud Vision API shows null object reference

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-vision

I am trying to build an android application where I am using `google cloud vision API` for detecting faces. I am following [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-the-google-cloud-vision-api-in-android-apps--cms-29009) tutorial. The problem is that, I am unable to produce the `toast message` that was supposed to be displayed on the screen after I click the button but the `logcat` shows:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.api.services.vision.v1.Vision$Images com.google.api.services.vision.v1.Vision.images()' on a null object reference

Here is the code :

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button upload_button;
private ImageView image_capture;
final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 100;

private Vision vision;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    upload_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadb);
    image_capture=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.capturedImage);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    5);
        }
    }

    Vision.Builder visionBuilder = new Vision.Builder(
            new NetHttpTransport(),
            new AndroidJsonFactory(),
            null);

    visionBuilder.setVisionRequestInitializer(
            new VisionRequestInitializer("AIzaSyAueQjrrY_GiXh7kNGlbDLKWhYP-4q77vI"));
    Vision vision = visionBuilder.build();

    upload_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /*Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);*/
            imageDectection();
        }
    });
}

private void imageDectection() {
    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.crewf);
                byte[] photoData = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

                Image inputImage = new Image();
                inputImage.encodeContent(photoData);

                Feature desiredFeature = new Feature();
                desiredFeature.setType("FACE_DETECTION");

                AnnotateImageRequest request = new AnnotateImageRequest();
                request.setImage(inputImage);
                request.setFeatures(Arrays.asList(desiredFeature));

                BatchAnnotateImagesRequest batchRequest = new BatchAnnotateImagesRequest();
                batchRequest.setRequests(Arrays.asList(request));

                BatchAnnotateImagesResponse batchResponse =
                        vision.images().annotate(batchRequest).execute();

                List<FaceAnnotation> faces = batchResponse.getResponses()
                        .get(0).getFaceAnnotations();

                int numberOfFaces = faces.size();

                String likelihoods = "";
                for(int i=0; i<numberOfFaces; i++) {
                    likelihoods += "\n It is " +
                            faces.get(i).getJoyLikelihood() +
                            " that face " + i + " is happy";
                }

                final String message =
                        "This photo has " + numberOfFaces + " faces" + likelihoods;

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

            } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.d("ERROR", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

The picture is stored in `/res/raw` location as `crewf.jpg`. I have tried setting the types as `LABEL_DETECTION`,`TEXT_DETECTION`,`LANDMARK_DETECTION` but none of it works.

Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing the Vision object.

You should declare two class variables:

```
private Vision.Builder visionBuilder = new Vision.Builder(
                                                new NetHttpTransport(),
                                                new AndroidJsonFactory(),
                                                null
            ).setVisionRequestInitializer(new VisionRequestInitializer(BuildConfig.GOOGLE_API_KEY));
private Vision vision;
```

Then on the onCreate build the object:

```
vision = visionBuilder.build();
```

After that, you're ready to go.

If you're still facing troubles email me, I could help you reviewing your code.